# IronPython does not find module although path is correctly set

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, python.net

In my C#-Application (x64) I use `IronPython` (v2.7.7 installed via nuget) to execute python code. I installed `python 2.7 x64` manually and installed the package `spacy` in it. I can find it at `C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\spacy`.

When executing the C# code, I get the `ImportException` from `IronPython.Runtime` "No module named spacy". The resources that I found online claim that it should be resolved with adding the correct path, however, that doesn't seem to suffice in my case.

The python code (as you can see in the string variable in the C# code below) is

```
import sys
print sys.version
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27x64\Lib')
import spacy
```

C# code:

```cs
string code = @"
import sys
print sys.version
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27x64\Lib')
import spacy";
var setup = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.GetEngine(runtime);
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Python27x64\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
var executable_code = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.Statements);
executable_code.Execute(scope);
```

The output is

> 2.7.7 (IronPython 2.7.7 (2.7.7.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit))

followed by the `IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException`: No module named spacy.

So neither adding the path in C# nor adding it in the python code seems to do the magic. I also tried adding the path 'C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages', but that's an illegal path for some reason.

Update: I tried copying the spacy directory to C:\Python27x64\Lib, which seemed to work (it complained about pathlib), but after I also copied pathlib, it failed again with "ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form".

The stack trace (which I find utterly unhelpful in this case) is:

```
at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Types.DocBuilder.GetXPathDocument(Assembly asm)
at IronPython.Runtime.Types.DocBuilder.GetXmlDoc(Type type, String& summary)
at IronPython.Runtime.Types.DocBuilder.CreateAutoDoc(Type t)
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonTypeOps.GetDocumentation(Type type)
at IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonTypeInfo.DocumentationDescriptor.TryGetValue(CodeContext context, Object instance, PythonType owner, Object& value)
at IronPython.Runtime.Binding.MetaPythonType.FastGetBinderHelper.SlotAccessDelegate.Target(CodeContext context, Object self, Object& result)
at IronPython.Runtime.Types.TypeGetBase.RunDelegatesNoOptimize(Object self, CodeContext context)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.DynamicGetMemberExpression.GetMemberInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.MakeClass(FunctionCode funcCode, Func`2 body, CodeContext parentContext, String name, Object[] bases, String selfNames)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
at Backend.python.ExternalTransform.Execute(Object input, String code) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\code.cs:line 20
at Backend.python.ExternalTransform.Test() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\code.cs:line 32
at Backend.python.Tests.ExternalTransformTests.TestTest() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\code.cs:line 17
```

Result Message: 
Test method Backend.python.Tests.ClassName.Test threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Spacy is written in Cython and will only work with pythonnet, but not IronPython.

Comment: @denfromufa thanks, that's very helpful. Is there a nuget package for pythonnet?

Comment: There is, but it wasn't updated lately. Let me try to update today. In the meantime install CPython and then do `pip install pythonnet`

Comment: @denfromufa I've tried the existing pythonnet nuget package, but it seems to be 32bit only. Do you have information on the release schedule?

Comment: You need to install CPython runtime from Python.org, much like IronPython installation. Then use pip or conda to install Spacy and pythonnet. Nuget for all pythonnet versions will not be released soon due to this issue: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/165

Comment: pythonnet v2.3.0 comes with nuget packages: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation